# Magento Prototype Form Validation

Tags: php, magento, prototype

I am working with form validation in magento with prototype validation.js

The validation works very fine for form but only once. It means once I try to submit form without content then it shows me error on those fields which is required.

Then if I fill all fields then error messages remains there: http://prntscr.com/47bss7

[image]

That means it validates but when it shows me the errors, then in same time I add content then errors remain same and not allow me to submit form.

Thanks

Comment: i just want to explain little more if error comes in form then not allow me to submit form every we fill whole content properly.

Comment: Show us the phtml file of your form, and the validation JS you are using to apply the Varien form validator.

Comment: here is my form screenshot ( http://prntscr.com/47bvp0 )

Comment: here is validate.js link (  http://tbf.me/a/BFxJrK )

Comment: one more thing i want to epxlain that we just upgrade from jquery 1.10.x to jquery.1.11.x

Comment: Your form code looks fine, which means it's most likely a conflicting script or modification you've made causing the issue.  Start with a clean, unmodified version of Magento and then work back in your modifications. You haven't really provided us the whole picture, so there's no possible way to properly debug.  You need to debug the issue using the process of elimination.

Comment: Please explain me which picture you want. I already post validation.js , form , view screenshot. Which other screenshot you want to see...

Comment: Sorry, but we cannot debug your code for you because you have not provided the necessary means of recreating the problem.

Comment: By recreating the problem, I mean actually being able to see the problem in action.  Posting a picture of code and a Magento JS file is not enough.

Comment: Axel thanks for your kind replay I already solve the problem. Problem was that one of the js file ( animation.js ) was conflicting with prototype we don't need that and I just remove that file now everything works fine thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the js file ( animation.js ) was conflicting with prototype.

Removing animation.js solved the problem.